# XML Schema element restrictions based on usage

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I've defined a element named `transform`

```
<xs:element name="transformName" type="xs:string"/>
```

I'd like to use that element in various other elements. For example

```
<xs:element name="input">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="transformName"/>
            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="output">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="transformName"/>
            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I know I can restrict what can be put in transform name using something like

```
<xs:element name="transformName">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="transform\.\S+\.\S+\.\d{1}\.v\d+"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

But is there any way to vary the restriction for each parent element?

For example, when used in input it might be:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="inputTransform\.\S+\.\d{1}"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

But when used in output it might be:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="outputTransform\.\S+\.\d{1}"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

Comment: Of course this is possible. And you're halfway through it. Define a type for each possibility/parent element. From here, it depends on the layout of your whole XML file (and your XSD impl). So knowing the XML would be helpful. If nothing else helps, you'd have to use XSD-1.1 to match a RegEx. But a [mcve] would still be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow ... what do you mean by "Define a type for each possibility/parent element."  I'd be happy to provide more of an example but the schema and XML include much more than just this.  I was try to keep my examples focused. Unfortunately, I'm limited to XSD 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you say that you are restricted to XSD-1.0, I avoid using `xs:alternative`. By

> "Define a type for each possibility/parent element."

I do mean to create a `type` for each `xs:pattern`.
So, for a sample XML like this:

```
<root>
    <input>
        <transformName>inputTransform.A.1</transformName>
        <description />
    </input>
    <output>
        <transformName>outputTransform.C.2</transformName>
        <description />
    </output>
</root>
```

...the XSD-1.0 code that validates it could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="input">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="transformName" type="tnInput" />
                            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="output">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="transformName" type="tnOutput" />
                            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="tnInput">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="inputTransform\.\S+\.\d{1}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="tnOutput">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="outputTransform\.\S+\.\d{1}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

See that it defines a different `simpleType` with a different `xs:pattern`  for each parent element (`input`/`output`).

---

To avoid this, you'd have to use the XSD-1.1 `xs:alternative` approach which could look like this:

```
<xs:element name="transformName" type="xs:string">
    <xs:alternative test="ancestor::input"  type="inputType"/>
    <xs:alternative test="ancestor::output" type="outputType"/>
</xs:element>
```

I couldn't make this work, but it's the way to go if you want to keep one element as a reference.